# Change a value of a variable in memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a field token_number in my database which i want to assign 1 more than the previous record.

for example in terms of array

```
 token_number[2] = token_number[1] + 1
```

And the value would be 1 for the first record. How can a assign a variable in the model which changes everytime i create a new record from my controller.

And my next condition is that the variable be reset to 0 every time when the current time i.e Time.now is the midnight. I tried it like this

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
    before_create :update_token_number

private
    def update_token_number
        date = Time.now
         time_zone = Time.zone # any time zone really
         timeday = time_zone.local(date.year, date.month, date.day)
         midday = timeday.beginning_of_day
        if date == midday
            num = 0
            num = num + 1
        else
            num = num + 1
        end
            self.token_num = num
        #end
    end
end
```

if it runs also the value given to the field is always 1.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to right a `rake task` using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to reset token_number to 0. Something like

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 am' do
  runner "Ticket.reset_token_number"
end
```

and use the `before_create` callback to update the value as you mentioned in the code snippet.

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :update_token_number

private
  def update_token_number
    self.token_num +=1
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to change method to class method `self.update_token_number`

Comment: @promond thanks but could u please tell me in detail as i m not that well aware of rake task. Sorry to bother but if u could elaborate it then could be big help. If i m missing anything in information then please ask....

Comment: @Mannish If you go through the documentation of whenever gem, https://github.com/javan/whenever. You will get to know how to schedule tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would not manually create tokens like this. 
I think you should try [Json Web Token Gem](https://github.com/garyf/json_web_token).

Comment: that would be great if i could do it with gem, I will try anyhow but want to learn this as well so that i can be confident in future while doing other stuffs relating to this issue, Thanks